# ReplyRequiredException on attempt to get data from <int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>?

Tags: spring-integration

I would like to define an
`<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway/>` with `query` and without `update` to retrieve data from database. Then I would like to use the `int-jdbc:outbound-gateway` as an implementation of `Service.findSomeData()` interface method. The data retrieved from interface implementation is used in my custom transformer's `CheckService` class. See the configuration below:

```
<int:service-activator method=“performCheck”>
       <bean class=“com.example.service.CheckService”
             c:service-ref=“service”
 </int:service-activator>

<int:gateway id=“service” service-interface=“com.example.service.Service”>
   <int:method name=“findSomeData” request-channel=“jdbcChan” reply-channel=“jdbcChanReply”/>
</int:gateway>

<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway request-channel=“jdbcChan”
                          data-source=“pooledDs” row-mapper=“dataRowMapper” reply-channel=“jdbcChanReply”>
   <int-jdbc:query>
       select some, data from some_table
   </int-jdbc:query>
```

The problem is that I get `ReplyRequiredException` exception when I move my payload to `jdbcChan`:

> org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyRequiredException: No reply produced by handler 'org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcOutboundGateway#0', and its 'requiresReply' property is set to true.

I decided to pay more attention on [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/7f3c7dd3e4dd6a776db33d0c861c161672a9241f/basic/jdbc/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/spring-integration-context.xml#L39) located in spring in **spring-integration-samples** repository on GitHub, but looks like it also does not work as expected. I get exactly the same exception in example project trying to find User by name `foo`. You can easily reproduce the exception with [basic jdbc example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/7f3c7dd3e4dd6a776db33d0c861c161672a9241f/basic/jdbc/) located on GitHub and the following test method:

```
@Test
public void findPerson() {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "/META-INF/spring/integration/spring-integration-context.xml");
    PersonService service = context.getBean(PersonService.class);
    final List<Person> foo = service.findPersonByName("foo");
    assertThat(foo, is(not(empty())));
}
```

Am I doing it wrong or there is a bug in latest Spring Integration JDBC? (for me looks like even example is broken)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [fixed the sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/commit/ca8704265c9132f8b3f420f78b05b2a08b8bfb9c?w=1).

We changed the default for `requires-reply` to `true` a long time ago but the sample was never updated.

> `assertThat(foo, is(not(empty())));`

However, the `List<Person>` is `null` when no results are received.

**EDIT**

> But I would expect empty list instead of a null if ResultSet was empty.

That's not how it works.

If the resultSet is empty, `null` is returned (hence the original error you were seeing).

If the resultSet has 1 entry, just that entry is returned.

Otherwise a list of entities is returned.

```
Object payload = list;
if (list.isEmpty()) {
    return null;
}
if (list.size() == 1) {
    payload = list.get(0);
}
return payload;
```

It's been like that forever but I believe the single Object Vs. List is wrong (if `maxRows > 1`).

`maxRows` is 1 by default so it made sense then; however, if `maxRows` is > 1 and only 1 row is returned I think it should still be a list of 1. The application shouldn't have to check the type of the result. It either expects a list or a single object (or null). [INT-4559](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4559).

Comment: Thanks. I checked and it works now if you add a Person to a database. But I would expect empty list instead of a `null` if ResultSet was empty.